# NSTimer incrementing whenever I get back to that view

Tags: ios, nstimer

I declared an nstimer on this event here:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                                   userInfo:_TimeLabel.text repeats:YES];

}
```

although its correct, the timer adds 1 more timer whenever I get back to this UITableViewCell causing a blinking effect (which is soooo noticeable specially when done back and forth). how do i fix this? is there a way to load the timer once and ignore the declaration once i get back to this UITableViewCell? pls help me. Im a newbie in Xcode.

Comment: TableCellController ?

Comment: sorry i mean a UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

layoutSubViews is called many a times. You can't be sure about when its called. When ever the view notices some changes and needs to re-render, then its layoutSubViews method is called.

I think for some reason layoutSubView is called twice.

Instead , `initialise your timer in ViewDidLoad` of ViewController.